# Generate nested json layout using list

Tags: python, json

I have created json requests form from data available in csv file.

***Sample Input file :***

```
Id,LineNo,Amt,ReceivedDt,FromDt,ToDate,regionId
123545,1,1000.00,2019-02-01T00:00:00,2019-02-01T00:00:00,2019-02-01T00:00:00,WA12
123545,2,200.00,2019-02-01T00:00:00,2019-02-01T00:00:00,2019-02-01T00:00:00,WA12
123545,3,200.00,2019-02-01T00:00:00,2019-02-01T00:00:00,2019-02-01T00:00:00,WA12
123546,1,200.00,2019-02-01T00:00:00,2019-02-01T00:00:00,2019-02-01T00:00:00,WA13
123546,2,200.00,2019-02-01T00:00:00,2019-02-01T00:00:00,2019-02-01T00:00:00,WA13
```

Earlier the requirement was to achieve below layout :

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "ToDate": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
            "ReceivedDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
            "regionId": "WA12",
            "Id": "123545",
            "LineNo": "1",
            "Amt": "1000.00",
            "FromDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00"
        },
        {
            "ToDate": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
            "ReceivedDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
            "regionId": "WA12",
            "Id": "123545",
            "LineNo": "2",
            "Amt": "200.00",
            "FromDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00"
        },
        {
            "ToDate": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
            "ReceivedDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
            "regionId": "WA12",
            "Id": "123545",
            "LineNo": "3",
            "Amt": "200.00",
            "FromDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "data": [
        {
            "ToDate": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
            "ReceivedDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
            "regionId": "WA13",
            "Id": "123546",
            "LineNo": "1",
            "Amt": "200.00",
            "FromDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00"
        },
        {
            "ToDate": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
            "ReceivedDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
            "regionId": "WA13",
            "Id": "123546",
            "LineNo": "2",
            "Amt": "200.00",
            "FromDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

And I was able to achieve it using below code :

***Code :***

import csv
import json
import itertools
import operator

```
with open('Test.csv') as f:
    cf = csv.DictReader(f)
    output = [{'data': list(rows)} 
        for id_, rows in itertools.groupby(cf, key=operator.itemgetter('Id'))]
data = json.dumps(output, indent=4)
print(data)
```

But now, it got changed and the regionID must come separately.I am not sure how to pick just one value of the regionId linked with the Id and pass it in the list. Please notice change in the placement of regionID below. Also, please let me know if there is any other way to achieve required layout.

***Desired output :***

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "ToDate": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
            "ReceivedDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
            "Id": "123545",
            "LineNo": "1",
            "Amt": "1000.00",
            "FromDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00"
        },
        {
            "ToDate": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
            "ReceivedDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
            "Id": "123545",
            "LineNo": "2",
            "Amt": "200.00",
            "FromDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00"
        },
        {
            "ToDate": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
            "ReceivedDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
            "Id": "123545",
            "LineNo": "3",
            "Amt": "200.00",
            "FromDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00"
        }
    ],
    "regionId": "WA12"
},
{
    "data": [
        {
            "ToDate": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
            "ReceivedDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
            "Id": "123546",
            "LineNo": "1",
            "Amt": "200.00",
            "FromDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00"
        },
        {
            "ToDate": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
            "ReceivedDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
            "Id": "123546",
            "LineNo": "2",
            "Amt": "200.00",
            "FromDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00"
        }
    ],
    "regionId": "WA13"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In[2]: import collections
  ...: import csv
  ...: 
  ...: by_region = collections.defaultdict(list)
  ...: with open('infile.csv', 'r') as f:
  ...:     reader = csv.DictReader(f)
  ...:     for row in reader:
  ...:         region = row.pop('regionId')
  ...:         by_region[region].append(row)
  ...: 
  ...: result = []
  ...: for key, value in by_region.items():
  ...:     result.append({
  ...:         'data': value,
  ...:         'regionId': key
  ...:     })
  ...: 
In[3]: import json; print(json.dumps(result, indent=2))
[
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "Id": "123545",
        "LineNo": "1",
        "Amt": "1000.00",
        "ReceivedDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
        "FromDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
        "ToDate": "2019-02-01T00:00:00"
      },
      {
        "Id": "123545",
        "LineNo": "2",
        "Amt": "200.00",
        "ReceivedDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
        "FromDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
        "ToDate": "2019-02-01T00:00:00"
      },
      {
        "Id": "123545",
        "LineNo": "3",
        "Amt": "200.00",
        "ReceivedDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
        "FromDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
        "ToDate": "2019-02-01T00:00:00"
      }
    ],
    "regionId": "WA12"
  },
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "Id": "123546",
        "LineNo": "1",
        "Amt": "200.00",
        "ReceivedDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
        "FromDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
        "ToDate": "2019-02-01T00:00:00"
      },
      {
        "Id": "123546",
        "LineNo": "2",
        "Amt": "200.00",
        "ReceivedDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
        "FromDt": "2019-02-01T00:00:00",
        "ToDate": "2019-02-01T00:00:00"
      }
    ],
    "regionId": "WA13"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Pop it off the row and attach it to the outer dict:

```
with open('Test.csv') as f:
    cf = csv.DictReader(f)
    output = []
    for _, rows in itertools.groupby(cf, key=operator.itemgetter('Id')):
        region_id = None
        for row in rows:
            try:
                region_id = row.pop('regionId')
            except IndexError, KeyError:
                pass
        output.append({'data': list(rows), 'regionId': region_id})
```